# ObjectInputStream catch block produces EOFException?

Tags: java, objectinputstream, eofexception

Sorry to drag this up but I have had a good look around and I still keep getting an EOFException. I've commented everything out of my method apart from:

```
    File receivedFileObject;
    File newFile = new File("newlyWrittenFile.mp3");


    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT);

        try{
        ObjectInputStream incommingData = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

All I'm trying to do is pass a file, txt or mp3 from the server to the client - I don't even try to call `readObject()` on the `ObjectInputStream` and yet I still get EOFException? How can I reach the end of a file I haven't tried to read? In actual fact I wish I was trying to read a text file line by line, because I know how to do that perfectly fine. I just want to receive an Object, cast it to a file and write it to the file system but for some reason my catch block :

```
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Incomming data assignment error : " + e);   
        }
```

prints out :

> Incomming data assignment error : java.io.EOFException

I have been trying to follow along with the server code listed in [this forum post](http://www.java-forums.org/networking/25669-sending-file-server-client-saving-file-clients-computer.html). Basically from the server I use the following lines to write the file to the client:

```
        if (myFile.exists()) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        oos.writeObject(myFile);
    }
```

I would be really grateful if someone could explain how to fix what feels like a stupid error on my part - Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the code where you are writing to the ObjectOutputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ObjectOutputStream` is used for serializing a java object to a stream. It is unlikely that you want to do this.

If you want to "pass a file", that probably means you want to "pass the *contents* of the file", so just to this:

```
FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream("newlyWrittenFile.mp3");
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = // pseudo code for reading all bytes from input
newFile.write(bytes); // pseudo code for writing to file
newFile.close();
```

You might find apache common-io library `IOUtils` class methods quite handy to read and write your data easily

Comment: Thanks for this reply but my end goal is to actually stream mp3's over a network as opposed to waiting for entire files to download. Am I rite in saying a stream is the correct technology to use just I don't have much experience am eager to get things done.

Comment: Yes use a stream, but do *not* use an ObjectOutputStream. There must be 1000's of examples on the web for sending bytes over a socket - just use google. You'll basically want to "pump" a `FileInputStream` to a socket's `OutputStream`. Apache's IOUtils can do that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [javadoc of `ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified.

So creating the object does trigger a read.

Comment: Ah I see, that's interesting. So what can I do to stop it generating the exception? How can I put anything "down the pipe" so to speak without this happening ?